# How to set the Owner of certificate generated by Let's Encrypt?

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate, letsencrypt

I've implemented Let's Encrypt on two production servers with relative ease, and both servers are providing certificates to the websites we run on those servers.

What's bugging me though is when you view the certificate information, and the "Owner" isn't defined. Instead, this message is provided (viewed using Firefox):

> This website does not supply ownership information.

The sites are a mix of e-commerce and normal websites, but I'd like to add the company's ownership information to the certificate. I am, however, unable to find any information about how to do this.

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do that with Let's Encrypt, which only issues "domain validated" certificates (i.e., ones based solely on being able to demonstrate control of the domain).

If you really want the ownership info to show up, you'll need to purchase an [Extended Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) certificate, which involves an additional identity validation process.